# Intellij idea. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

Tags: intellij-idea, database-connection, sslhandshakeexception

After the IntelliJ idea update, I got the exception when trying to connect to DB.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate).
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution is simple.

Database tab → Data Source Properties

[image]

→ select DB → Advanced → enabledTLSProtocols set TLSv1.2.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**step1**

[image]

**step2**

[image]

### database tab -> properties -> select db -> try `Test Connection`

edit VM options: delete **SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1,**

Comment: We have updated our base Java to Java11 and this started to happen and this solution works well.

To clarify the instructions here is the exact string I used, and you can copy and paste it into the VM Option.

`"-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,TLSv1,TLSVv.1"`

Leave the quotes in when pasting.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me. I'm using tls version 1.0 in mysql server, so to fix the problem I used "-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3" this one